# API endpoint not found (404), but there (next js)

Tags: node.js, next.js, nodemailer

I'm sending (nodemailer) a link to the user to verify his account. The email is sent successfully.

**The problem: The link doesn't work. I get a 404 error "Not found".**

Here's what I'm doing backend to send the email with the link:

```
// send email with verification link    
handler.post(async (req, res) => {
      const { email, id } = req.body;
      const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_BASE_URL;
    
      if (email && validator.isEmail(email)) {
          const dataMail = {
            from: " ... ",
            to: " ... ",
            attachments: [
              {
                filename: "logo.png",
                path: "public/assets/logo.png",
                cid: "/logo.png",
              },
            ],
            subject: "... ",
            html: `<p>Please verify your account:</p><a 
                  href="${baseUrl}/api/verification/${id}" target="_blank">ACTIVATE 
                  ACCOUNT</a>`,
          };
    
          try {
            await emailService.sendMail(dataMail);
            await knex("User")
              .update("status", "pending")
              .where("id", id);
          } catch (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
              message: "Something went wrong",
            });
          }
```

And here's what should happen backend after the user clicks on the link:

```
// /api/verification/[id].js
handler.post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await knex("User").where("id", req.query.id);

    if (!user) {
      res.sendStatus(401).json({ message: "Something went wrong." });
    } else {
      await knex("User")
        .update({ status: "active", date: new Date() })
        .where("id", req.query.id);

      const redirectPath = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIRECT_VERIFICATION;

      res.redirect(redirectPath);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

My folder structure looks as follows:

- api/verification/[id].js

Any ideas what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: I see that you handle a post request, but the link is making a get requests

Comment: If the user "clicks on the link" in the email, it's executing a `GET` reqeust ... you only have `POST` handlers

Comment: @KonradLinkowski derpirscher: OMG! You're right! Such a silly error!! This took me a few hours! Now everything works! Thank you so much!!!